# What is wrong with this Java date format?

Tags: java, parsing, date, format

A parser for email messages contains the following data format definition:

```
private final static DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");


if (line.startsWith("Date:")) {
        try {
            email.date = dateFormat.parse(line.substring(6));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
                System.err.println("Unparsable: " + line.substring(6));
        }
```

This code prints the error:

```
Unparsable: Mon, 15 Jan 2001 23:18:00 -0800 (PST)
```

Why do the formats not match?

```
EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

Comment: Does it work without the "(PST)" at the end?

Comment: This seems to work `new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").parse("Mon, 15 Jan 2001 23:18:00 -0800 (PST)")`

Comment: If it's not the Locale problem pointed out by @JonSkeet, it could conceivably also be threading issues (SimpleDateFormat is not thread-safe), but that seems unlikely.

Comment: [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me - but then I'm in an English locale to start with. That may be the problem - try explicitly specifying the locale when you construct the `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
private final static DateFormat dateFormat =
    new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.US);
```

Otherwise your current system locale will be used, and if that's not English it will be trying to parse different month and day names.

Answer (score 0):

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    Date date=dateFormat.parse("Mon, 15 Jan 2001 23:18:00 -0800 (PST)");
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

I tried this and it pritns

```
   Tue, 16 Jan 2001 13:18:00 +0600
```

I am not getting any errors